# How to set value of all structure members at once?

Tags: c

How can I set structure members using a single line of code?

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}test;

test obj[2];
int main()
{

 obj[0].x=0; //this works
 obj[0].y=0; //this works
 obj[0]={0,0};  //compilation error

}
```

Comment: Look at the first answer to the question I linked. You're trying to use the syntax for initialization when you're doing an assignment which won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Structs can be assigned to with the `=` operator, exactly the same way as any other value in C:

```
obj[0] = existing_test;
obj[1] = function_returning_test();
```

The above rely on struct values that have themselves come from somewhere else in the program (possibly having been initialized in multiple statements like in the question); to create a struct value in a single expression, use the *object literal* syntax:

```
obj[0] = (test){ .x = 15, .y = 17 };
obj[1] = (test){ .y = 19 };
```

Any fields left out of a such a literal are still present, but set to the appropriate zero value for their type, so in the above example `obj[1].x` is set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to set the values to zero, the following line of code should work:

```
memset(&obj,0,sizeof(obj));
```

However, it is only going to work if you want the values initialized to zero

Comment: memset is **dangerous** function!
Some slowly but safely in this way >
**obj = Obj_Type{}**;

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialize **all values** in your **array of structs** in a **single line of code** when the **instance is created**. (not including use of `memset`). Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} test;

int main()
{
    test obj[2] = { { 3, 5 }, { 4, 6 } };
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf ("\n  obj[%d].x = %d  obj[%d].y = %d\n", i, obj[i].x, i, obj[i].y);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
obj[0].x = 3  obj[0].y = 5

obj[1].x = 4  obj[1].y = 6
```

**Note:** normal initialization is to `0`, but different values were used to illustrate the point.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can assign a structure value to a structure variable. Think of `obj[0]` is some address of memory.

But you can do it during array of structure initialization:

```
test obj[2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}};
```